# How does one properly load the lats in a powerlifting Benchpress?

Tags: bench-press

I have been searching the a lot but I can't find any good explanations on this. One cue that seems to get at this is "bending the bar", but I think this cue is detrimental to my bench. Could someone explain how to engage lats more in the powerlifting bench with maybe some cues?

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the "Bend the barbell" cue is to get you to tuck your elbows inward in front of the bar rather than flaring them outward. As you try to "bend the bar" outward, you end up tucking your elbows inward as well as helps you keep a strong grip on the bar.  It's really only helpful in the lowering phase of the bench to ensure that you're in a more optimal position when the bar reaches your chest.

If "Bending the bar" doesn't work for you, then you can try the opposite end which is "pull the elbows in" or "tuck elbows". Doing so should achieve the same result.

Another cue some people use is "pull the barbell down" similar to how you would a lat pulldown. This cue gets people to really engage the lats and keeps you really tight.

Comment: You mean, pull the barbell down horizontally, right?

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller No.  I meant literally pull it as if you were trying to row it. It's not a very common cue because as you're probably wondering how that's possible when the bar is falling to you, but some people can feel the sensation of their lats engaging by mimicking the movement pattern.  I probably should not have included that in the original answer tbh.